# Rolles Theorem Simple and multiple zeros

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I have this problem with Legendre polinomials

**Use Rolle's Theorem to show that Pn cannot have multiple zeros in the open interval (-1, 1). In other words, any zeros of Pn which lie in (-1, 1) must be simple zeros.**

The question is that Im a little bit confuse about what is multiple zeros and simple zeros.

Comment: $(x-2)^3=0$ has triple zero at $x=2$. While $x-2=0$ has a simple zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the complex numbers, any polynomial $p$ splits into a product of linear factors, that is: $p(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$. Consider a root $\alpha_k$ of $p$, then we say this root is *simple* if $\alpha_k\neq \alpha_j$ for any $j$.